# parsing a reponse from a XMLHttpRequest

Tags: ajax, feedparser

I'm struggling with how to parse a response from an XMLHttpRequest. The response is in json format:

```
http://flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=75564008a468bf8a284dc94bbd176dd8&tags=paris&format=json
```

to make sure it does indeed come in as such i tested it:

```
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = this.responseText
```

which returns me a page with a long line of data written in json format. Could someone help me figure out the next steps in order to extract data from the response i.e. a list of all titles

i did some research and came across this:

```
response = this.responseText ;
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response, "text/xml");
```

what do i need to do next?
(Note: i wish to do this manually i.e. without the help of jQuery or similar tools.)

**[EDIT]**

based on the suggestions below and on the [Flickr page on that matter](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html), i have tried the following:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
 ...
            if (this.responseXML != null)
            {
                jsonFlickrApi(this.responseText) ;

                function jsonFlickrApi(rsp){

                    for (var i=0; i<rsp.photos.photo.length; i++){

                        var blog = rsp.photos.photo[i];

                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        var txt = document.createTextNode(photo.owner);

                        div.appendChild(txt);
                        //document.body.appendChild(div);
                        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML.appendChild(div);
                    }
...
}
```

this doesn't return anything visible yet.

**[EDIT2]**

further troubleshooting reveals:

```
rsp = this.responseText ;
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = rsp.stat ;
```

prints `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cool thing about JSON is that it's actually executable code. You don't need to do any "manual" parsing – just run the code. Perhaps Flickr supplies a function called jsonFlickrApi with their API libs that they exepct you to use, but you could just as well supply your own.

```
function parseFlickrJson(jsonstring){
    var data=null;

    var jsonFlickrApi=function(d){
        data = d;
    }

    eval(jsonstring);

    return data;
}

myreturndata = parseFlickrJson(response);

// Try getting something from the object
alert(myreturndata.photos.pages);
```

Comment: in jsonFlickrApi=function(d)  ...what does 'd' do or where does it come from?

Comment: @all: thanks also for your help! it was a difficult choice to pick an answer to accept. i went for the one that had most practical value in the given situation. thanks again.

Comment: If you haven't figured out already, d is the parameter that is being sent to jsonFlickrApi. The JSON files contains a single call to jsonFlickrApi with all the data declared as an inline JS object.

Answer (score 2):

The URL you've given returns somethins like this :

```
jsonFlickrApi({"photos":{"page":1, "p ... , "stat":"ok"})
```

So, basically, it looks like Javascript code, which :

- Calls the `jsonFlickrApi` function,
- Passing it a big JSON object as a parameter.

First of all, here, you are working with JSON, so you should not use any DOM-related stuff : DOM functions' goal is to help manipulate XML.

Instead, you should :

- Write a `jsonFlickrApi` function,
- Make sure it's called when you receive the data from Flickr

About that, you shuld find a bit more informations, and an example, here : http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Else, adding the `&nojsoncallback=1` parameter at the end of the URL of your request, you'll get pure-JSON as a result *(and not a function-call)*.

That would allow you to use standard JSON-manipulation functions to work with that data, not having to implement any specific function.

Between those solutions, up to you to choose which one you prefer :-)

Comment: Hi Pascal, thank you very much for your feedback. As you can see i'm quite new to this so i'm exploring...ideally i would like to get back XML and then use DOM parsing which seems to have many advantages e.g. being, hopefully, straightforward. But my URL doesn't return anything if i remove '&format=json' at the end. I only get back an object without accessible nodes. What would you suggest in this regard? re SON-manipulation functions, are they built into PHP? or do i need to use a library?

Comment: If I remove the `&format=json`, I get XML as a response -- note that, in that case, `responseXML` will be an interpreted XML object *(and not the XML string, thats in `responseText`)* ;;; about JSON manipulation in PHP, you have the `json_decode()` function.

Comment: Pascal said:"responseXML will be an interpreted XML object"... that's exactly where i stumble because i can't access the nodes. why does it not come in the way i want it? :)

Comment: Hu... well, because that's the way it works ;-) you'll have to find out how to work with the `responseXml` object *(it's not that hard -- but not that simple either... which is probably why many prefer JSON)*

Comment: After a bit of fiddling, it seems like Firefox and Chrome are blocking cross-site requests. See my XML reply.

Comment: Yes, cross-site requests are not allowed, with XmlHttpRequest -- that's the *same origin policy* security thing, implemented by browsers.

Answer (score 1):

A different alternative is not to use JSON at all, and use XML instead. Leave out the `format=json` part of the URL and you get the data as XML. This XML can be parsed, for example with the `DOMParser()` method you tried, or with `this.responseXML`. However, the "logistics" of using XML, compared to JSON, are a bit more complicated, as you're browsing a DOM tree and not a JS object.

**Update:**

So here's one of the murky details of AJAX. Depending on the browser, you can't just make XML requests between domains. The following code will work (return something useful) on Safari, but not Firefox or Chrome. (There, it will return null or empty strings.) The JSON requests seem to work fine without on all browsers, however.

```
<script>
function createXHR(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  if (window.ActiveXObject){
    // code for IE6, IE5
    return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  return null;
}

function getFlickr(){
  xmlhttp=createXHR();

  url="http://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=75564008a468bf8a284dc94bbd176dd8&tags=paris&";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
     alert(xmlhttp.getAllResponseHeaders());  
     alert(xmlhttp.responseXML)
     alert(xmlhttp.responseText)
     var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;

  }
}

getFlickr();
</script>
```

Comment: HI nitro2k01, when i do this I only get back an object without accessible nodes i.e. responseXML is an object whereas responseText gives me something tangible, hence the json approach but yes if i could i would also tru the xml approach